# Remove duplicate in a list which contains arrays

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a `list<array[]>` in Java, and I want to remove from it all duplicates.

In addition, the array `[1,2]` is the same as array `[2,1]`.

I want to use Set, but as I understand it, if I declare 2 arrays: `int[] array1 = {1, 2}` and `int[] array2 = {1,2}`, Java considers them as 2 different arrays. In addition, It doesn't help me in the case of `[1,2]` and `[2,1]`

How can I do it?

Comment: "_I want to use Set_" do it. Two sets with the same content are considered the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not tested but you can do sort the array before adding into `set`

```
int[] array1 = {1, 2};
Arrays.sort(array1);
set.add(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashSet and then add all the contents of your current list(s) into it. Then use the .toArray() method to get back a list.

```
HashSet<Integer> noDuplicates = new HashSet<Integer>();
Integer[] array = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
for (Integer i : array)
  noDuplicates.add(i);
array = noDuplicates.toArray(new Integer[] {});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

If you have to check if two arrays are the same often, then you might just want to use a Set instead of an array as it'll save you the extra step of putting everything into a Set and then checking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `Iterator` to iterate the `list`.
2. Use `Arrays.equals(arg0, arg1)` method to compare arrays inside `list`.
3. If you find equal arrays remove using `iterator.remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int[]> b = new ArrayList<int[]>(); // Your list here
for (int[] ar : b) {
    Arrays.sort(ar);
}
Set<int[]> a = new HashSet<>(b);
```